# LGSVL AssetBundles files are zero-length

Tags: unity-game-engine, simulator

I have following general setup for LGSVL simulator:

- Windows 10
- Unity 2019.3.15.f1
- 2020.06

In the options I selected only Windows support.
The issue is that after doing WebUI/main build the AssetBundles files, like environment files or vehicle file have zero length and thus cannot be used by the simulator.
I haven't done anything special to assets after cloning Git repos, but I followed all steps for building the simulator as per instructions.
Do I miss some preparation steps with assets?
Do I have to prepare/build them somehow separately?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake was I selected Windows support only.
After reinstalling proper Unity version with Linux Mono enabled, it worked like a charm.